# Hide password with "•••••••" in a textField

Tags: swift, passwords

In my app there is a textField where the user have to put is password in and i want that when he enter a character it change it to '•' how can i do this?

Answer (score 335, accepted):

You can achieve this directly in Xcode:

[image]

The very last checkbox, make sure `secure` is checked .

Or you can do it using code:

Identifies whether the text object should hide the text being entered.

**Declaration**

```
optional var secureTextEntry: Bool { get set }
```

**Discussion**

This property is set to `false` by default. Setting this property to `true` creates a password-style text object, which hides the text being entered.

**example:**

```
texfield.secureTextEntry = true
```

Comment: In the New XCode8 and above we have to add secureTextEntry  in runtime attribute column

Answer (score 67):

**in Swift 3.0 or Later**

```
passwordTextField.isSecureTextEntry = true
```

Answer (score 17):

## Swift 4 and Xcode Version 9+

Can be set via "Secure Text Entry" via Interface Builder

[image: Secure Text Entry checked via storyboard screenshot]

Comment: Hi, Sometimes secure textfield highlights yellow with text "Strong Password" error, Is there any solution?

Comment: @Saravanan if you don't auto generated password please change content type *Password* to *defualt* or other option

Answer (score 13):

In Xcode 6.3.1, if you use a `NSTextField` you will not see the checkbox for `secure`.

Instead of using `NSTextField` use `NSSecureTextField`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssecuretextfield

I'm guessing this is a Swift/Objective-C change since there is now a class for secure text fields.  In the above link it says `Available in OS X v10.0 and later.`  If you know more about when/why/what versions of Swift/Objective-C, Xcode, or OS X this

Comment: For MacOS development, this is the new correct answer

Answer (score 6):

For SwiftUI, try

```
TextField ("Email", text: $email)
    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle()).padding()
SecureField ("Password", text: $password)
    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle()).padding()
```

Answer (score 2):

Programmatically (Swift 4 & 5)

```
self.passwordTextField.isSecureTextEntry = true
```

Comment: For swift 3 and later the syntax was changed, refer to the answers above.

Comment: My answer is for Swift 4

Comment: Are you sure that this is Swift 4? There is no property or method named secure for a textField... for swift 4 we use self.passwordTextField.isSecureTextEntry = true

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using properties of textfield from Attribute inspector

Tap on Your Textfield from storyboard and go to Attribute inspector , and just check the checkbox of "Secure Text Entry" [SS is added for graphical overview to achieve same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26K6h.png)